# If index is 0 (i === 0 in for loop), do something, else do something else. Not going through the else case

Tags: javascript

I have this code, and it's not going through the 'else' case in the for loop.

```
function ArithGeo(arr) 
{
    var arithStep = 0, geoStep = 0, arith = [], geo = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
        if (i === 0) 
        {
            arithStep = arr[i + 1] - arr[i];
            geoStep = arr[i + 1] / arr[i];
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Not going here.
            console.log("i !== 0");
            if (arr[i] - arr[i - 1] !== arithStep) 
                arith.push("false");

            console.log(arr[i] / arr[i - 1]);

            if (arr[i] / arr[i - 1] !== geoStep) 
                geo.push("false");
        }

        if (geo.indexOf("false") == -1) 
            return "Geometric";
        else if (arith.indexOf("false") == -1) 
            return "Arithmetic";
        else 
            return -1;
    }
}

// Arithmetic example: [2, 4, 6, 8] and Geometric example: [2, 6, 18, 54].
console.log(ArithGeo([2, 4, 8, 15]));
```

Also tried `else if (i !== 0)` but that doesn't trigger the block either.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vAW7d/

Comment: Because you are `return`ing.

Comment: The problem isn't the condition. The `return`s are interrupting the `for` loop as they force the `function` to exit.

Comment: `return` ends the function immediately. When you `return` on the first iteration of the loop, no further iterations run.

Comment: Instead i === 0 have you tried i == 0? Or invert the condition: if(i !== 0) else

Comment: You have return in your method.

Comment: Probably just need to remove `else { return -1; }` and put `return -1` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're returning in the first iteration. This causes the engine to leave the function entirely, so it doesn't even have a chance to test `i` after that.

Try moving the second `if`/`else` block to after the `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

if (geo.indexOf("false") == -1) {
    return "Geometric";
} else if (arith.indexOf("false") == -1) {
    return "Arithmetic";
} else {
    return -1;
}
```

On a side note, you can improve this algorithm a bit by using Boolean values rather than arrays. Simply set `geo` and `arith` to `true` initially, then set them to `false` if you happen to find a non-geometric / non-arithmetic step. This also makes it easier to short-circuit certain evaluations in your code. For example, you can break out of the loop immediately when you know it's neither a geometric or arithmetic sequence.

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/vAW7d/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm always looking for ways to make my solutions more elegant / efficient, and I won't be forgetting this advice ;)